# npm install/uninstall modifies packages.json

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I've recently upgraded to node8 (using nvm) and a weird things started to happen in one of the project I'm working on.

Node v8.11.1
Npm 5.6.0

I cd inside my project having a packages.json.
For dev purposes I wanted to remove some packages previously installed but I didn't want to modify my packages.json.

Whenever I run either `npm uninstall package-name` or `npm install packages-name` they both try to install all the missing packages listed in packages.json!

I am explicitly NOT passing the `--save` or `--save-dev` flag but still npm ignores that.

I think it might have to do with `package-lock.json` file?

**Q:** How to tell npm I do not want it to mess up with other packages or modify my packages.json?

Comment: Why do you have dependencies in your package.json file if you don't want them installed?

Comment: Read carefully "For dev purposes I wanted to remove some packages previously installed"

Comment: I don't know if you were trying to be snarky but... ok.  If you're using source control you should be able to branch your environment and change your package.json so you're not attempting to do something this hacky.

Comment: I am trying to `npm link` packages I am developing in local to substitute packages I have installed from npm. These packages from npm comes with their deps and they conflicts with the new deps I am relying on for the new packages I am developing and linking. So I don't want to remove them from my packages.json, I just want to temporarily uninstall them so I could clean install the `npm link`-ed version